# Are there any statistical model that could learn an arbitrary probability distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks, references

I have the follow problem:

I need a statistical model or machine learning method that allow me to parameterize a probability distribution into a finite number of parameters $\theta$. That's mean, given $\theta$, I would get the distribution function $F_\theta(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$. But I still need the following feature:

1. I can compute the probability density function $f_\theta(x)$ easily
2. I can compute the inverse $F^{-1}_\theta$(y)
3. Hopefully it is easy to compute the gradient of $\log f_\theta$ for me to find the MLE of $\theta$. (It is okay if there is another  statistical inference technique)

I have thought the following way:

1. Parameterize $F_\theta$ by a neural network and then use a sigmoid function at the end of the network to enforce the output to $[0,1]$ But then I don't have any idea how to guarantee the function that I learnt is monotonic increasing in $x$.
2. Parameterize $f_\theta$ by a neural network and then use an exponential function $\exp(\cdot)$ at the end of the network to enforce the output to be positive. 
   But then I suffer from the problem that computing $F_\theta(x)$ and $F^{-1}_\theta(x)$ are difficult.
3. Use a mixture model with many components to model the distribution function.

Are there any existing statistical model or machine learning deal with such problem?